# jQuery cycle pause on hover over next/prev

Tags: jquery, cycle

I'm new to jquery cycle, so my apologies in advance if this is simply a dumb question. I've set up a slideshow on my site and everything is working fine. However... my slideshow is set to pause when hovering over the *image*, when what I really want is to pause when hovering over the 'next' or 'prev' buttons. I'm guessing it's very basic, but I've searched all over and can't find the answer.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#s2').cycle({ 
fx: 'fade', 
speed: 800,
timeout: 4000, 
next: '#next2', 
prev: '#prev2',
after: onAfter,
fastOnEvent: true,
pause: 1 
});
});
function onAfter(curr,next,opts) {
var caption = 'Photo ' + (opts.currSlide + 1) + ' of ' + opts.slideCount;
$('#caption').html(caption);
}
</script>
```

**Related HTML:**

```
<div id="s2" class="pics">
<a href="coral_natural_stone_1lg.jpg"><img src="coral_natural_stone_1.jpg" width="1000" height="450" alt="Palm Beach Cast Stone - Coral and Natural Stone" /></a>
<img src="coral_natural_stone_2.jpg" width="1000" height="450" alt="Palm Beach Cast Stone - Coral and Natural Stone" />
<img src="coral_natural_stone_3.jpg" width="1000" height="450" alt="Palm Beach Cast Stone - Coral and Natural Stone" />
<img src="coral_natural_stone_4.jpg" width="1000" height="450" alt="Palm Beach Cast Stone - Coral and Natural Stone" />
<img src="coral_natural_stone_5.jpg" width="1000" height="450" alt="Palm Beach Cast Stone - Coral and Natural Stone" />
<img src="coral_natural_stone_6.jpg" width="1000" height="450" alt="Palm Beach Cast Stone - Coral and Natural Stone" />
<img src="coral_natural_stone_7.jpg" width="1000" height="450" alt="Palm Beach Cast Stone - Coral and Natural Stone" />
</div>

<p id="caption"></p>

<div class="nav"><a id="prev2" href="#"><img src="prevbttn.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="previous" /></a><img src="spacer.gif" width="10" height="10" alt="spacer" /><a id="next2" href="#"><img src="nextbttn.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="next" /></a></div>
```

**And the related CSS:**

```
.pics {  
width:   1000px;  
height:  450px;  
padding: 0;  
margin:  0;  
} 

.pics img {  
padding: 0px;  
border:  none;  
background-color: #ffffff;  
height:  450px;  
width:   1000px;  
top:  0; 
left: 0;
}

#caption {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 75%;
color:#2769b5;
}
```

Any help anyone could provide will be more appreciated than you can imagine. I know this is probably a simple thing to do, but I honestly have exhausted my resources (and about 15 pages worth of google results!). Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Teresa

ADDED ON 1/13:

Revised my code as noted below, but still not working (the jsfiddle below works perfectly, exactly what I'm looking for, but even with straight copy/paste not working on my end). Something obvious, I'm sure, but struggling. Here is my revised js code and relevant info in my header (html and css have remained the same):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#s2').cycle({ 
fx: 'fade', 
speed: 800,
timeout: 4000, 
next: '#next2', 
prev: '#prev2',
after: onAfter,
fastOnEvent: true
});
});
function onAfter(curr,next,opts) {
var caption = 'Photo ' + (opts.currSlide + 1) + ' of ' + opts.slideCount;
$('#caption').html(caption);
}

$('#next2, #prev2').hover( 
function() { 
    $('#s2').cycle('pause'); 
}, 
function() { 
    $('#s2').cycle('resume'); 
} 
);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, remove the `pause: 1` from the options -- this is what causes it to pause on image hover. Then:

To pause, you can use:

```
$('#s2').cycle('pause')
```

and to resume, you can use:

```
$('#s2').cycle('resume')
```

This code should achieve what you're looking to do:

```
$('#next2, #prev2').hover( 
    function() { 
        $('#s2').cycle('pause'); 
    }, 
    function() { 
        $('#s2').cycle('resume'); 
    } 
);
```

Comment: I was working on the jsfiddle example and saw Chris answered already. To avoid me adding a new answer, the jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wUZC9/).

Comment: Exactly what I want it to do. Your jsfiddle works perfectly, is straightforward and makes sense. BUT, it doesn't work for me and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Straight copy/paste on the js, and all the html and css is straightforward and unchanged. Spent the last two hours trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong, and I'm sure it will probably be something simple and obvious. I can't fit my new edited code in this box, so I'll edit my question above and place it there. I'm going to cry tears of joy if I get it to work! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _You cannot safely manipulate a page until the document is “ready.”_ I've [made an update to the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wUZC9/1/) from @flynfish to reflect the correct code.

Comment: Thank you both so much for the help! It's working exactly as it should and I've learned some things in the process. What an awesome feeling when something finally works. (My neighbors probably heard my sigh of relief, which is a lot better than what they were hearing earlier!). Thank you again, can't tell you how much I appreciate the help.

Comment: @TeresaThayer Glad that I could help! If my answer solved your problem, please [mark it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as the accepted solution

Answer (score 0):

for cycle2 paused on hover you only beed add:

```
...
data-cycle-pause-on-hover: "#s2",
...
```